# What determines the coefficients in the definition of slugging percentage?

Tags: baseball, statistics, sabermetrics

When calculating [slugging percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slugging_percentage), why do the numbers of singles, doubles, and triples get multiplied by 2, 3 and 4, respectively, in the numerator? And, perhaps related, why does the HR count remain as is without a coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have the definition of slugging percentage wrong. [Quoting from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slugging_percentage):

> [Slugging percentage] is calculated as total bases divided by at bats
>
> SLG = ((1B) + (2 x 2B) + (3 x 3B) + (4 x HR)) / AB

i.e. singles are multiplied by one (not two), doubles by two (not three), triples by three (not four) and home runs by four (not one).

Comment: Got it. Much appreciated. Seems my source was misinformed. I had trouble believing that the weight was as such. Yours makes perfect sense.